# Retaining a value from a response in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js

On page load, say for a particular route for (e.g. `https://localhost:8000/home/index`), a service is called and the response from the service is rendered to the page at the client side.

On the same page, I have a link that pops up a Backbone.js modal and from the modal a click event triggers which hits another url (e.g. `https://localhost:8000/home/index2`) upon which another service call triggers and the response is rendered to another html page.

On the same html page, I want to display a value which I got from the first service call on page load. However, I am unable to retain that value as there are two different requests each time. Hence, I cannot even append the value from first response to the request object and use it a second time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JavaScripts Web Storage API to storage information on client browser.

[MDN Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API)

For example, If you are on the first screen and call a service, store the service information on localStorage

`localStorage.setItem('firstService', serviceResponseObject);`

Once you are navigated to second page, you can use localStorage to read to previous service information

`localStorage.getItem('firstService');`

Comment: More information here for InCognito mode http://htmlui.com/blog/2011-08-23-5-obscure-facts-about-html5-localstorage.html

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to store state between requests.

From the server, if you're using say Express etc, you could store the result in a Session.  Or you can even store state in the requests query params, or from a POST request.

You could also store some data on the client end, using say Cookies or localstorage.

What you choose really depends, it might be best if you explain in more detail what sort of information your passing between pages.

If it's just a simple value, I would go for using query params.
eg. Just place in your url `https://localhost:8000/home/index2?value=123`,  and then from node.js,  `req.query.value` would have your value.